# Grid Algorithm, similar to WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, grid

**Edit**
Upon further reading and experimenting my reformulated questions :

How do I measure a Star Column Contents, specially when the contents of the grid can span multiple Cols/Rows?

If I have a Control that is inside Col 0, and it spans 2 cols.
and Col 0 is a Star Col, what size would the column actually take? 
Or am I missing something?

**EDIT:** 
  Since it seems I didnt explain myself well enough, what I actually need to do is find how to make each of the contents mesure themselfs and report back to the actual Col/Row. My issues is mostly, what happens when a control spans multiple rows, I might be missing something on the grid actually works.

I would like to implement a GRID similar to WPF Grid, but I am having trouble understanding how the algoritm to Mesure the Grid actually works, currently I have something like this :

```
    protected override Size MesureOverride(Size s)
    {
        int colCount = Columns.Count;
        int rowCount = Rows.Count;
        bool emptyRows = rowCount == 0;
        bool emptyCol = colCount == 0;
        if (emptyRows)
            rowCount = 1;
        if (emptyCol)
            colCount = 1;
        rows = new GridSegment[rowCount];
        cols = new GridSegment[colCount];


        if (float.IsNaN(s.Width))
        {
            //We are trying to mesure our size top
            //Find what our contents width is
        }
        if (float.IsNaN(s.Height))
        {
            //find what our contents height is
        }
        CreateCells(s, emptyRows, rows, cols, emptyCol);
        float gridWidth = 0;
        float gridHeight = 0;
        foreach (var col in cols)
        {
            gridWidth += col.DesiredSize;
        }
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            gridHeight += row.DesiredSize;
        }
        float mesureHeight = 0f;
        float mesureWidth = 0f;
        foreach (var v in this.Childreen)
        {
            var layoutInfo = v.Layout<GridLayoutInfo>();
            var rowspan = layoutInfo.RowSpan;
            var colspan = layoutInfo.ColumSpan;
            float width = 0;
            float height = 0;
            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            if (rowspan < 1)
                rowspan = 1;
            if (colspan < 1)
                colspan = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < layoutInfo.Row + rowspan && i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && i <= layoutInfo.Row)
                    y += rows[i - 1].DesiredSize;
                if (i >= layoutInfo.Row)
                    height += rows[i].DesiredSize;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < layoutInfo.Column + colspan && i < colCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && i <= layoutInfo.Column)
                    x += cols[i - 1].DesiredSize;
                if (i >= layoutInfo.Column)
                    width += cols[i].DesiredSize;
            }
            v.Mesure(new Size(width,height));
            //Calculate the grid size            
        }
        return new Size(gridWidth, gridHeight);
    }

    private void CreateCells(Size s, bool emptyRows, GridSegment[] rows, GridSegment[] cols, bool emptyCol)
    {
        float avaiableWith = s.Width;
        float avaiableHeight = s.Height;
        if (!float.IsNaN(Width))
            avaiableWith = Width;
        if (!float.IsNaN(Height))
            avaiableHeight = Height;


        float totalRowFixed = 0;
        float totalColFixed = 0;
        float maxStarRow = 0;
        float maxStarCol = 0;
        if (emptyRows)
        {
            rows[0] = new GridSegment(0, 0, float.PositiveInfinity, MesureType.Start);
            rows[0].Stars = 1;
            maxStarRow = 1;
        }
        else
            for (int index = 0; index < Rows.Count; index++)
            {
                var v = Rows[index];
                rows[index] = new GridSegment(0, v.Min, v.Max, v.Type);
                var current = rows[index];
                if (current.Type == MesureType.Fixed)
                {
                    //our desired size in units
                    current.DesiredSize = Mathf.Clamp(v.Value, current.Min, current.Max);
                    totalRowFixed += current.DesiredSize;
                }
                else if (current.Type == MesureType.Start)
                {
                    current.Stars = v.Value;
                    maxStarRow += current.Stars;
                }
            }

        if (emptyCol)
        {
            cols[0] = new GridSegment(1, 0, float.PositiveInfinity, MesureType.Start);
            cols[0].Stars = 1;
            maxStarCol = 1;
        }
        else
            for (int index = 0; index < Columns.Count; index++)
            {
                var v = Columns[index];
                cols[index] = new GridSegment(0, v.Min, v.Max, v.Type);
                var current = cols[index];
                if (current.Type == MesureType.Fixed)
                {
                    //our desired size in units
                    current.DesiredSize = Mathf.Clamp(v.Value, current.Min, current.Max);
                    totalColFixed += current.DesiredSize;
                }
                else if (current.Type == MesureType.Start)
                {
                    current.Stars = v.Value;
                    maxStarCol += current.Stars;
                }
            }

        //TODO::ADD THE AUTO SIZED DEFs
        //Calculate the sizings for all * columns 
        {
            var starColumns = cols.Where(x => x.Type == MesureType.Start);
            var stepStarColl = (avaiableWith - totalColFixed) / maxStarCol;
            foreach (var gridSegment in starColumns)
            {
                gridSegment.DesiredSize = stepStarColl * gridSegment.Stars;
            }
            var starRows = rows.Where(x => x.Type == MesureType.Start);
            var stepStarRows = (avaiableHeight - totalRowFixed) / maxStarRow;
            foreach (var gridSegment in starRows)
            {
                gridSegment.DesiredSize = stepStarRows * gridSegment.Stars;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size s)
    {
        int colCount = Columns.Count;
        int rowCount = Rows.Count;
        bool emptyRows = rowCount == 0;
        bool emptyCol = colCount == 0;

        if (emptyRows)
            rowCount = 1;
        if (emptyCol)
            colCount = 1;
        rows = new GridSegment[rowCount];
        cols = new GridSegment[colCount];
        CreateCells(s, emptyRows, rows, cols, emptyCol);
        ////Loop through all controls
        foreach (var v in this.Childreen)
        {
            var layoutInfo = v.Layout<GridLayoutInfo>();
            var rowspan = layoutInfo.RowSpan;
            var colspan = layoutInfo.ColumSpan;
            float width = 0;
            float height = 0;
            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            if (rowspan < 1)
                rowspan = 1;
            if (colspan < 1)
                colspan = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < layoutInfo.Row + rowspan && i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && i <= layoutInfo.Row)
                    y += rows[i - 1].DesiredSize;
                if ( i>= layoutInfo.Row )
                    height += rows[i].DesiredSize;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < layoutInfo.Column + colspan && i < colCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0 && i <= layoutInfo.Column)
                    x += cols[i - 1].DesiredSize;
                if (i >= layoutInfo.Column)
                    width += cols[i].DesiredSize;
            }
            v.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, width, height));
        }
        float gridWidth = 0;
        float gridHeight = 0;

        foreach (var col in cols)
        {
            gridWidth += col.DesiredSize;
        }
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            gridHeight += row.DesiredSize;

        }
        return new Size(gridWidth, gridHeight);
    }
```

This is from my custom library, but I tried to keep it as close to WPF syntax as possible.

This code works almost as I want, but fails once the grid is inside a ScrollingContainer, since the size passed to the measure is Infinity, and it makes the grid take on a infinity large size.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this, I am not even using Auto Cols/Rows, since I thought it would simplify the Alg alot - I dwelled into the source of WPF, but I have major hard time trying to understand how it works.

Comment: just curious.. have you used the debugger to step through all that code you just posted.. can you pinpoint in your code using the debugger where the disconnect is happening..?

Comment: From [FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx): **Parameters** *availableSize ... The available size that this element can give to child elements. Infinity can be specified as a value to indicate that the element will size to whatever content is available*. This means that your Grid should arrange all its Children according to their DesiredSize.

Comment: I have been hitting my head on this a few days...

@Clemens yes, If I pass a limited size, the grid does work perfectly.But if this is inside a Element that can scroll for example, the size passed is PositiveInfinity, which in turn with my current code, makes the grid size to infinity. I can't seem to make it arrange to the desired size correctly.
Maybe I am not understanding something in these passes, for example if its a * Colum and infinity is passed, the column width should be its contents width?But if this is the case, then I should pass infinity width to the child elements right?

Comment: @MethodMan I have debugged, and I know what is causing it, I just can't seem to actually build the algorithm to measure the contents when the grid is   inside a "infinite panel". I might be not completely understanding the Infinity Rules on WPF.

Comment: @clemens taking in account what you said, and further reading on the subject, I do agree that that's what's missing, my question being.
How do I measure a Star Column Contents, specially when the contents of the grid can span multiple Cols/Rows? This is exactly what I can't seem to understand.